# Accessing element after JSON loaded new content

Tags: javascript, json

Here is the reference to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexFromMoscow/rdxnmzsp/).
It is only the markup and a snippet of javascript so it doesn't work as it should in real web. But this is not the case.

What I want is to access the element inside the new content (i.e. `<div class="frame frame-id4">`) **after** AJAX loads it.
Inside the `if` function console returns exactly what I need, i.e. see `//CASE 1` (in the bottom of Javascript section of jsfiddle).
But if I try to access the same element outside that `if` function I get `//CASE 2`. 
Is there any way to access `<div class="frame frame-id4">` within this function ?

Comment: Show your function. You aren't showing us anything trying to access your new div.

Comment: We need to see the JavaScript. My guess is that you are doing something Asynchronous.

Comment: JavaScript via AJAX loads, JSON is simply a data format.

Comment: Fixed, thank you John. Any ideas on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

Using `xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);` instead of 
 `xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);` does the trick.